# Docker-compose --force-recreate specific service

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a container in my stack that needs to be recreated each time I `docker-compose up`. I can `docker-compose up --force-recreate` but this recreates *all* my containers. Is there syntax (maybe for the docker-compose.yml file) for specifying this kind of flag per-service?

Comment: Is this in swarm mode? `docker-compose up` doesn't work with swarm mode.

Comment: No, this is just straight docker-compose, sorry for the confusion, I've edited the question.

Answer (score 53):

If your service depends on (or links to) other services, you can try:

```
docker-compose up --force-recreate --no-deps service-name
```

This will only recreate the specified service, linked or depended services will keep untouched.

Comment: Note - `service-name` is name defined in `docker-compose.yml` (so `php`, not `project_php_1`).

Comment: `docker compose up -d --force-recreate --no-deps service-name`
Worked for me thanks.

Answer (score 2):

to rebuild only 'mysql' service, run this command

```
docker-compose up --force-recreate --no-deps mysql
```

Comment: What does it add to the earlier, most upvoted answer?

Comment: Its just add some more explanation with an example service i-e "mysql".